# Python; Append vector to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got

```
Xa = [a1,a2,a3]
Xb = [b1,b2,b3]
Xc = [c1,b2,b3]
```

And I want

```
X = [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,b2,b3]]
```

Im using numpy append, concatenate, hstack, vstack, and others functions, but them doesnt work or gives me this

```
X = [a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,b2,b3]
```

Also after this process I will need to append Xd, Xe, Xf and so on, so I need a way to add these vectors to the array as they come.

Any ideas on what Im doing wrong or what to do?

Comment: Edit your question to make it clear where you want numpy arrays, and where you are happy with lists.  Regarding your use of `vstack` etc, show us how you used the functions and what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack` :

```
Xa =np.array(['a1','a2','a3'])
Xb =np.array( ['b1','b2','b3'])
Xc = np.array(['c1','b2','b3'])

>>> np.vstack((Xa,Xb,Xc))
array([['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
       ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
       ['c1', 'b2', 'b3']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple if just simple array.
initialize an empty array and keep appending your arrays to it.

```
Xa = ['a1','a2','a3']
Xb = ['b1','b2','b3']
Xc = ['c1','b2','b3']
```

Empty array

```
resultArray = []
resultArray.append(Xa)
resultArray.append(Xb)
resultArray.append(Xc)
```

output:

```
[['a1','a2','a3'], ['b1','b2','b3'], ['c1','b2','b3']]
```

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: You aren't using arrays here, at least not numpy ones.  You using Python lists.

Comment: @hpaulj OP didn't said he had numpy array. he just mentioned he used various methods. i just took OP code and put the result as he wanted.

Comment: The OP was sending mixed signals, showing lists, but tagging the question with numpy and mentioning various numpy functions.  As well as talking about arrays and vectors.  But since he accepted your answer, that numpy stuff must have been a mistake.